# How to loop through a typed Viewbag list?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, list, for-loop, document-ready

I've passed in a `List<AdminUsers>` via the Viewbag to a view.The list is then assigned to a javascript var and looped through.

But during debug on the view this for loop is never looped through, although I've set a breakpoint on it.

The purpose of the loop is to check if any of the users in the `adminUserList` match the currently logged in user. The `currentUser` is init also so that rules out this value being null.

In order to debug the reason for this. I tested that the `Viewbag.AdminUserList` is assigned and init in the controller which it is. I also set an alert in the view on this list and it is init.

**Question:**

Does anyone know why the below `for loop` isn't called in javascript?

This is the value of the js adminUserList during debug:

```
var adminUserList = [{"AdminID":1,"AdminDisplayName":"brianb","AdminEmailAddress":"brian@test.com"},{"AdminID":2,"AdminDisplayName":"wendy","AdminEmailAddress":"wendy@test.com"}];
```

**Code:**

Javascript for loop -

```
<script>

    var currentUser = '@ViewBag.CurrUser';
    var adminUserList = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.AdminUserList));

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var historyTable = $('#table').DataTable({
            "order": [[6, "desc"]]
        });

        //Loop through each of the admin users, if any of
        //the admin users match the current user, hide the delete column.   
        for (var i = 0; i < adminUserList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (currentUser == adminUserList.AdminDisplayName[i]) {
                //hide the delete table option from a non admin user
                historyTable.columns([9]).visible(false);
            }

        }    

    });


</script>
```

Controller Index method -

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
            HistoryDAL sqlConnection = new HistoryDAL();
            List<AdminUsers> adminList = sqlConnection.GetAdminUsers();

            //Get the current user
            var components = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\');
            var userName = components.Last();

            //Assign current user and admin list to viewbag
            ViewBag.CurrUser = userName;
            ViewBag.AdminUserList = adminList;

            return View("Index");

    }
```

Model - AdminUsers:

```
public class AdminUsers
{
    public int AdminID { get; set; }
    public string AdminDisplayName { get; set; }
    public string AdminEmailAddress { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: What is the value of adminUserList?

Comment: @JohnMc I posted the value of the list above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line

```
for (var i = 0; i < adminUserList.Count; i++)
```

You need to use the JavaScript `adminUserList.length` rather than the C# `adminUserList.Count`, because `adminUserList` is a JavaScript variable not a C# one.

Comment: The for loop is working now as I tested by placing an alert inside. But the if condition is failing in that script on debug. I can't get a definite reason why yet. Any ideas?

Comment: How is it failing?

Comment: I can't tell as the breakpoint doesn't fire on the if condition. I see that after the alert within the for loop no code after that fires.

Comment: This looks wrong... if (currentUser == adminUserList.AdminDisplayName[i])   Should it be if (currentUser == adminUserList[i].AdminDisplayName) ?

Comment: My mistake I had placed the index in the wrong position.